# How to change my font in powershell using $Profile

Tags: json, windows, powershell, oh-my-posh

I am trying to work on customizing my powershell 7 experience using $Profile and settings.json. The first issue I am running into is that when I call

oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression
Import-Module posh-git

in $Profile to access the updated nerdfont I have downloaded "CaskaydiaCove NF Mono" it does not load into my environment.

Note: There is every possibility that I am looking in the wrong place so feel free to suggest other avenues to accomplishing this.

I have successfully been able to get it to work by Launching terminal, editing the settings on the GUI and then launching powershell 7 from the dropdown. However I want to be able to manually make changes with $Profile and settings.json.

It seems like the issue is that I don't have a command in my $Profile to connect to settings.json to allow it to read the file but I cannot find a recommendation on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The font is a setting of your terminal, not Powershell. So, have a look at the docs for your terminal on how to change the font there once it's installed on your system.